# How to convert array of objects to indexed object of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing, arrayobject

[image]I have the following array and a picture of how the structure of it returns to me:

```
const connections = [1:{fromBox: 0, fromConnector: "port_0", toBox: 1, toConnector: "port_0"},
                     1:{fromBox: 0, fromConnector: "port_1", toBox: 1, toConnector: "port_1"}
                    ]
```

and I need to create an object with this structure to be compatible with my code:

```
"connections": {
    "0": {
      "fromBox": "0",
      "fromConnector": "port_0",
      "toBox": "1",
      "toConnector": "port_0",
    },
    "1": {
      "fromBox": "0",
      "fromConnector": "port_1",
      "toBox": "1",
      "toConnector": "port_1"
    }
  }
```

Looking at similar doubts I have understood that with a reduction method I should be able to achieve it but when trying to put the index, that they have in the array, into the object it gives me as if the elements of the array were undefined

```
      const connectionsKeys = Object.keys(connections);

      const result = connections.reduce((c, v) => {
        c[v.connectionsKeys] = c[v.connectionsKeys] || {}; 

        return c;
      }, {});
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: `connections` is not a valid array.

Comment: @palaѕн the array is returned to me by the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const connections = [{fromBox: 0, fromConnector: "port_0", toBox: 1, toConnector: "port_0"},
                     {fromBox: 0, fromConnector: "port_1", toBox: 1, toConnector: "port_1"}
                    ]


function convertToObject(arr){
  return Object.assign({},arr)
}

console.log(convertToObject(connections));
```

Answer (score 1):

The first picture from your post (the one from the console) differs structurally from the one assigned to the constant connections.
The picture translated into js code should look like this

```
const connections = [{1:{fromBox: 0, fromConnector: "port_0", toBox: 1, toConnector: "port_0"}},
                 {1:{fromBox: 0, fromConnector: "port_1", toBox: 1, toConnector: "port_1"}}
                ]
```

From this structure, you can do the following reduction to end up with the structure you need:

```
const result = connections.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    acc[index] = curr['1'];

    return acc;
  }, {});
```

Comment: thank, the original structure was a mistake from a previous function that I've corrected, but I take note from your solution 'cause I didn´t know how to correct it!! @answered many thanks